# Setting ArcPy environment variables with Python multiprocessing?

Tags: arcpy, parallel-processing

I have a script which uses ArcPy + Python multiprocessing.

Are ArcPy environment variables shared between separate Python processes?

If I write to `arcpy.env.extent` from within each process am I asking for trouble?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Environments aren't propagated from process to process, so changing extent in one won't affect the other at all.